# Is the preposition nach with "nach Updates prüfen" correctly applied?

Tags: preposition

Is this preposition really appropriate?
At least

> "nach Sicherheit prüfen"

should be wrong IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this preposition really appropriate?

No, it isn't.

There should be ***auf*** instead of **nach**:

> > “**auf** Updates prüfen”
> >
> > "**auf** Sicherheit prüfen"

But

> > “**nach** Updates **suchen**”
> >
> > "**nach** Sicherheitsmängeln **suchen**"

It boils down to the Infinitve forms of the verbs:

- prüfen, *auf*
- suchen, *nach*

Comment: And: *um Updates betteln*, *um Sicherheit betteln*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Yo. Ich kenne die kanonische Antwort nicht, Du hast mich kalt erwischt ;-). Ich weiss nicht welche Präpositionen für _prüfen_ oder _suchen_ sonst noch so denkbar wären.